# Is there anyway to publish new symbian applications

Tags: mobile, symbian, nokia

I have a symbian application to be distributed to my customers as some of them are still using old nokia phones.
But as we know nokia has already shutdown symbian store and not accepting any new applications any more .
I would like to know if there is any other way to sign and distribute the symbian applications .

Some vendors are still able to release new Symbian applications . I wonder how they are able to  do that .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you are using capabilities which are only requiring self-signed capabilities, then you can self sign the sis file. For capabilities requiring higher capabilities, as far as I know there is no ways on getting the signing done.

For stores, I also have no knowledge of any that would accept Symbian apps still, anyways, as the app can be installed from any source really, you could distribute them via any means you like, for example, you could simply provide a download link in your webpage.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply . Distributing app is not a problem once it is symbian signed  as we can just upload sis/sisx  file to some webserver .  But symbian devices will accept signed application only to be installed . I heard people are still able to make new applications which require higher capabilities ( for example VoIP application ) , so i thought there would be some way to get app signed ..